# Zip a folder while copying it

Tags: tar, cp, zip

Is it possible to zip a folder while copying it?
I want to copy a folder and then zip it, but this implies that I need for a while twice the space in my /mnt path, right?

```
/bin/cp -r /mnt/myfolder /mnt/new_folder ; tar -zcvf /mnt/new_folder.zip /mnt/new_folder
```

Is it possible to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: `tar != zip`  Imagine how surprised the ZIP user will be when they discover that the `.zip` file you sent them actually isn't a `.zip` file at all.  You'd be well-advised to use a `.tgz` or `.tar.gz` extension instead.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to open it with 7-Zip without problem, but I will fix the extension anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of copying the folder you could just zip it by using tar specifying the path of the target file: you could try

`tar -zcvf /mnt/new_folder.zip /mnt/myfolder`

the tar program does not replace your original folder...